# How to isolate for a specified variable in R?

Tags: r

I am trying to manipulate an equation y, which is currently in terms of x, to obtain an equation x in terms of y. I believe there should be a fairly simple solution to this problem which I am not finding.

Here is the specific equation in which I am trying to write in terms of t:

```
Q=2(1-exp(-t/3))
```

I have tried using the solve function but seem to keep running into various errors and believe the solve function cannot be used for this problem. Here is what I tried:

```
solve(Q=2(1-exp(-t/3)), t)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi Micah. Unfortunately, I have some trouble in understanding your question. Neither do I see an `x` nor an `y` in your equation. I also do not understand your example code `Q=2(1-exp(-t/3))`. Here you assign `2(1-exp(-t/3))` to a variable `Q` (better use `<-`). That works, if there is some variable `t` in your working space and fails otherwise. Do you want to solve this "equation" for `t`? Then `solve` is definitely not the function your looking for as it only solves linear equation systems and your equation is obviously not linear. You can try to linearize it or use an optimization strategy.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your response. My talk of x's and y's was speaking more generally. Yes, I am trying to solve the equation for ``` t ```. You're right, not sure why I was trying to use Q= to define my function rather than assigning with <-. Thanks for your input of linearizing or using an optimization strategy, not sure how to go about these as of now but will definitely look into them. Appreciate your help.

Comment: Why do you use R in the first place? The exponential function is bijective on the real line, so you can solve it by hand.

Answer (score 1):

With the 'Ryacas' package:

```
library(Ryacas)
yac_str("Solve(Q == 2*(1-Exp(-t/3)), t)")
# "{t== -3*Ln(-(Q-2)/2)}"
```